# AutoMapper complex type objects mapping C#

Tags: c#, automapper, complextype

In my method I got back results that contain several list of strings and list of complex type objects.

```
            var AcctLst = gd.validateGroupMembershipUploadDetails(_input);


            Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Entities.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput, Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput>();

            var result = Mapper.Map<Data.Entities.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput, Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput>(AcctLst);


            return result;
```

var AcctLst contains the sample data :

[image]

Data.Entities.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput

and

Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput

looks like

```
public class GroupMembershipValidationOutput
{
    public List<string> _validMasterIds { get; set; }
    public List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput> _validChapterCodes { get; set; }
    public List<GroupCodeValidationOutput> _validGroupCodes { get; set; }

    public List<string> _invalidMasterIds { get; set; }
    public List<string> _invalidChapterCodes { get; set; }
    public List<string> _invalidGroupCodes { get; set; }
}


public class ChapterCodeValidationOutput
{
    public string chpt_cd { get; set; }
    public string appl_src_cd { get; set; }
}



public class GroupCodeValidationOutput
{
    public string grp_cd { get; set; }
    public string grp_nm { get; set; }
}
```

I guess _validChapterCodes and _validGroupCodes throw the following exception :

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
ChapterCodeValidationOutput -> ChapterCodeValidationOutput
ARC.Donor.Data.Entities.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput -> ARC.Donor.Business.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput

Destination path:
GroupMembershipValidationOutput._validChapterCodes._validChapterCodes._validChapterCodes0[0]

Source value:
ARC.Donor.Data.Entities.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah damn. It's relatively simple. You just have to map the inner nested types first.

```
    var AcctLst = gd.validateGroupMembershipUploadDetails(_input);
    Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Entities.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput, Business.Upload.ChapterCodeValidationOutput>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Entities.Upload.GroupCodeValidationOutput, Business.Upload.GroupCodeValidationOutput>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Entities.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput, Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput>();

    var result = Mapper.Map<Data.Entities.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput, Business.Upload.GroupMembershipValidationOutput>(AcctLst);
    return result;
```

Then it works flawlessly.